# insert array value in excel cell using macro

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I had cell `A5` data as multiple line in a single cell,

```
 Line_1
 Line_2
 Line_3
```

Which I need to update in same cell by adding `"<p>"` to each line:

```
 <p>Line_1</p>
 <p>Line_2</p>
 <p>Line_3</p>
```

Comment: Any code that you have tried so far :) ? What do you want to add to each line? `<p>` tag? or `""` inverted commas?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a formula to do this actually. Assuming your text is cell A1:

```
="<p>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</p>" & CHAR(10) & "<p>") & "</p>"
```

Comment: +1 yep - no point writing code for this one. Unless the `OP`er has really simplified the problem but in reality he actually needs to target various cells or a load of cells. Not a great question!